# SQLite and Adobe AIR - no utf-8 characters

Tags: sqlite, actionscript-3, encoding, utf-8, air

I have problem with data which I want to fetch from SQLite database in my Adobe AIR application. I use Javascript.

In sqlite3 CLI when I use this query: select * from notes;
I get this result:

```
Cześć|8
Boa noite|12
Até logo|13
```

But when I want to get this data in AIR using:

```
dbQuery = new air.SQLStatement();   
dbQuery.sqlConnection = db;
dbQuery.text = "SELECT hello, id FROM sometable";
```

I have something like that:

```
Cze|8
Boa noite|12
At logo|13
```

All specific characters are removed.

Where could be problem and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered where was problem.

I added new entities using sqlite3 CLI and probably the values were inserted in wrong encoding, because when I inserted values like "łąśćźóż" using AIR Adobe application or importing data to database:

```
sqlite3 test.db < test.sql
```

values are saved in correct encoding and when I get them to application, they are displayed in correct encoding.